# If $f(x)$ is a twice differentiable function such that $f(x)+f''(x)>2f'(x)$ and $f(0)=0$ , $f(1)=9$, is $f(x) \geq $ or $\leq 9x^{x-1}$?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

> Let $f(x)$ be a twice differentiable function such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=9$ and $f(x)+f''(x)>2f'(x)$
> $ ~\forall x ~\in [0,1]$. Which of the following statements is true about $f(x)$?
>
> **A)** $f(x) \geq 9xe^{x-1}$
>
> **B)** $f(x) \leq 9xe^{x-1}$
>
> **C)** $f(x) \geq 27xe^{x-1}$
>
> **D)** None of the above

**Attempt:**

I assumed $g(x)=f(x)-9xe^{x-1}$ so that $g(0)=g(1)=0$.

Then I found $g'(x)=f'(x)-9e^{x-1}-9xe^{x-1}$ and $g''(x)=f''(x)-18e^{x-1}-9xe^{x-1}$. Now using $f(x)+f''(x)>2f'(x)$ , I obtained a similar relation for $g(x)$ as well , that is, $g(x)+g''(x)>2g'(x)$.

But this got me nowhere. I also assumed $h(x)=f(x)-f'(x)$ so that we have $h'(x)>h''(x)$, but from here  too I am unable to comment on anything that would lead me to prove either $g(x)\geq $ or $\leq 0$.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

A related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3720672/twice-differentiable-function-fx-satisfying-fxfx-2fx?noredirect=1), but it has an equality sign instead of inequality in the differential inequation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $$h(x)=f(x)\cdot e^{-x}$$ now it follows that
$$h''(x)=(f(x)+f''(x)-2f'(x))e^{-x}>0$$ so it is concave upwards hence recall that h(x) attains it maximum
at endpoints of intervals so $$h(x)\le \max (h(0),h(1))=?$$

Comment: How does that prove that $f(x) \geq $ or $ \leq 9xe^{x-1}$ ?

Comment: @LightYagami $h(0)=0,h(1)=9e^{-1}$ and the rest is easy  $e^{-x}f(x)\le 9e^{-1}$

Comment: Yeah, I got it. Thanks.

Comment: Are we just supposed to assume functions?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let $g=f\exp(-x)$. What equation do you get for $g''$?

> We get $g''>0$ from the given inequality. Thus it follows $g$ is convex.
>  From the definition of convexivity the curve must be below the line connecting the two endpoints. since $g(0)=0$ and $g(1)=\frac{9}{e}$ we know $$g(x)\le \frac{9}{e}x \implies f(x) \le 9x\exp(1-x)$$